# can't install vista

Tags: windows-vista, installation

i'm trying to install vista on my sister computer. I formated the C partition and everything has to go smooth, but it didn't. 
It makes a lot of noise(from the cooler) and it shout-down (not restarting). Arfter i porwer on again in order to continue setup I get this message:

> The computer restarted unexpectedly or
>   encountered an unexpected error.
>   Windows installation cannot proceed.
>   To install windows press OK button to
>   restart computer and then restart the
>   installation.

Which can be the cause? Any advices?

Comment: I don't think it's a witch. Don't believe in them, frankly.

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of noise"? Beeping, or rather scratching and screeching?

Comment: Was there an operating system on your sister's computer before you installed Vista? Was it working OK?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>As Gnoupi alluded to, if the noise is rattling or scratching it will likely be the harddrive is broken.</strike>

It's also possible that the installation didn't work properly and retrying it might solve the issue.

Is it a new computer, if not what operating system was on it before?

Comment: He edited his question since, noise was from the fan, so I guess simply it was a high activity. Or a faulty fan, eventually, but not a harddrive issue.